# Rewrite url pdf file

Tags: url-rewriting

i have website and show my `pdf` file with link `domain/assets/slipgaji/2014/4-2014/2004.06.0319.pdf` how to change a simple url with rewrite engine `.htacces` to `domain/2004.06.0319.pdf`

i tried with everithing rewrite rule on `.htaccess` and can't shown my file.

here my script eror

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} assets/slipgaji/[0-9]+/[a-z0-9]+.pdf$   
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/assets/slipgaji/fetch/$1 [L]
```